# Filter by search using text found in element within each div

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, filtering, show-hide

I found a fiddle that was useful for hiding text based on the text used in a search box, but have not been able to figure out how to adapt this method to a div with multiple elements in it. How could I change the jQuery in the attached fiddle to make it filter the div elements that match the search entered instead of the text found in the list items?

http://jsfiddle.net/point71echo/rof67uy6/2/

```
<input placeholder="Search Me" id="box" type="text" />

<ul class="navList">
    <li>apples</li>
    <li>apricots</li>
    <li>acai</li>
    <li>blueberry</li>
    <li>bananas</li>
    <li>cherry</li>
    <li>coconut</li>
    <li>donut</li>
    <li>durean</li>
</ul>


        <div class="connect-cat" catname="apples" style="visibility: visible; display: block;">
            <a href="/connect/apples">
                <div style="padding:5px;cursor:pointer;">
                    <div>
                        <img width="60" class="cat-logo" src="http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS0rYdTsHK-IwuWCNA_xXq44v76dFH2wPc5wdErF9yWHty-wqY4Bg" alt="apples">
                    </div>
                    <span>apples</span>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>



        <div class="connect-cat" catname="apricots" style="visibility: visible; display: block;">
            <a href="/connect/apricots">
                <div style="padding:5px;cursor:pointer;">
                    <div>
                        <img width="60" class="cat-logo" src="http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS0rYdTsHK-IwuWCNA_xXq44v76dFH2wPc5wdErF9yWHty-wqY4Bg" alt="apricots">
                    </div>
                    <span>apricots</span>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
```

Here's the jQuery used:

```
$('#box').keyup(function(){
   var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    if(valThis == ""){
        $('.navList > li').show();
    } else {
        $('.navList > li').each(function(){
            var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
            (text.indexOf(valThis) >= 0) ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();
        });
   };
});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> If I needed to add another text element to each div box, is there a way that all text in each div could be searchable? Here's the fiddle with one additional text element - jsfiddle.net/point71echo/mttgj1tt/1 –  point71echo

Here is a solution to search two elements at once in native JavaScript, without any libraries.

```
document.getElementById("box").onkeyup=function(){
  var matcher = new RegExp(document.getElementById("box").value, "gi");
  for (var i=0;i<document.getElementsByClassName("connect-cat").length;i++) {
    if (
      matcher.test(document.getElementsByClassName("name")[i].innerHTML) || 
      matcher.test(document.getElementsByClassName("category")[i].innerHTML)
    ) {
      document.getElementsByClassName("connect-cat")[i].style.display="inline-block";
    } else {
      document.getElementsByClassName("connect-cat")[i].style.display="none";
    }
  }
}
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mttgj1tt/5/)</kbd>

If you want to use jQuery to make it more readable (those stupid long DOM functions):

```
$("#box").on('keyup', function(){
  var matcher = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'gi');
  $('.connect-cat').show().not(function(){
      return matcher.test($(this).find('.name, .category').text())
  }).hide();
});
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jamen/mttgj1tt/8/)</kbd>

Comment: If I needed to add another text element to each div box, is there a way that all text in each div could be searchable? Here's the fiddle with one additional text element - http://jsfiddle.net/point71echo/mttgj1tt/1/

Comment: @point71echo, I know this is quite old, but I made an update for it anyways.  I made it better, and also added a jQuery version.

Comment: Using 'g' (global) in RegExp this way is wrong. It has a state which messes everything. Don't believe me? Try to search for "ra" and you would see only "orange" instead of also "radish". Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/mttgj1tt/39

Answer (score 4):

This should match only the divs with the class connect-cat, and filter by the span inside.

```
$('#box').keyup(function(){
   var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    if(valThis === ""){
        $('div.connect-cat').show();
    } else {
        $('div.connect-cat').each(function(){
            var text = $(this).find('span').text().toLowerCase();
            if (text.indexOf(valThis) >= 0) { $(this).show(); }
            else { $(this).hide(); }
        });
   }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/reyjose/40u0var6/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#box').keyup(function(){
    var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        if(valThis == ""){
            $('.connect-cat').show();
        } else {
            $('.connect-cat').each(function(){
            var text = $(this).find("span").text().toLowerCase();
            (text.indexOf(valThis) >= 0) ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();
        });
    };
});
```

If you have multiple "spans" in the div, simply add a class name to it. Then change

`var text = $(this).find("span").text().toLowerCase();`

to:

`var text = $(this).find(".spanClassName").text().toLowerCase();`

Answer (score 0):

Filter by search using text found in element within each div click button:
[image]

Comment: how to click with button search

Comment: add the jsfiddle link in the post plz.